# Send Headers during a curl call

Tags: php, html, curl

Hi I have to send a request to an api(pitney bowls geolocation) for which I need an access token from a site. In the website its mentioned as -
To get an access token, set header and request body and call the token URI:

```
Authorization: Basic {BASE64 ENCODED VALUE} 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
POST https://api.pitneybowes.com/oauth/token
grant_type=client_credentials
```

I am currently using the following code : -

```
$val= base64_encode ('{gR6Ov7fCmuzHcVXE6bsmcUOt3SXhmXlL}:{ud61in4FYSGyF0eU}');
 $ch = curl_init();
$headr = array();
$headr[] = 'Authorization: Basic {'.$val.'}';
$headr[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headr[]='grant_type=client_credentials';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.pitneybowes.com/oauth/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

However am not getting any result. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Only the first 2 seem to be valid header settings.

Comment: @jeroen- Even i think so. However in the api its written - To get an access token, set header and request body and call the token URI:.

So how exactly do i set the grant_type in request body or wherever

Comment: @jeroen - sorry if its a stupid question but I havent used curl before so...

Comment: I would think as `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

Comment: Hey @jeroen - It worked.. Thanks a lot!!! A lot... :)

Comment: I was just writing an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third header you are adding, is not a valid header.

You should probably add that as a POST key-value pair:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type=client_credentials');
```

Comment: Ya i did this with the help of your comment. Thanks @jeroen